# preg match multiple lines not working

Tags: php, regex

Websiste contains some codes like below..

```
</span></td>
    <td width="1%" align="right" nowrap="nowrap" class="small inner" >190 MB</td>
    <td width="1%" align="center" nowrap="nowrap" class="small inner" >15</td>
```

I need to get **190MB**

I tried below code..tried /s , /m nothing works..

```
preg_match_all('/<\/td>
    <td width="1%" align="right" nowrap="nowrap" class="small inner" >(.*?)<\/td>/m',$lol,$cooler);
```

Comment: Have you tried g
[http://regex101.com/r/wR0yN5/1] (regex101)

Comment: global modifier is implicit in the reg_match_all function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$lol = '</span></td>
<td width="1%" align="right" nowrap="nowrap" class="small inner" >190 MB</td>
<td width="1%" align="center" nowrap="nowrap" class="small inner" >15</td>';    

preg_match_all('/(?<=\<\/span\>\<\/td\>)[\n]?.*((?<=\>).+(?=\<))/', $lol, $cooler);

echo $cooler[1][0]; //Outputs "190 MB"
```

http://regex101.com/r/jY1pY9/1

Comment: i want only 190MB .. i need to match with </span></td> new lline

Comment: okay, see edit above

Answer (score 2):

Ew, parsing HTML with regex. Never a good idea.

Since there don't appear to be any handy identifiers that a parser could help you hook into, why not just `preg_match("/\d+\s*[KMG]B/`,$lol,$match); echo $match[0];`? Keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Then update the regex accordingly, as I have just done in my answer.